# jQuery class changed only acts once

Tags: jquery, ajax.net

I am changing button style when through jQuery when a button is clicked.
Below is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnDiv .down").click(function () {
            $(this).addClass("click");
        });
    });
```

Since i have  enclosed the #btnDiv in UpdatePanel the above functionality acts only once.
What is the reason and a work around for the problem.

Comment: What do you mean it acts only once?  You can't add the same class multiple times to the same element (at least, it wouldn't make sense to).

Comment: The problem is it when ever i click on button having a class .down it should change its class. My question is it was working fine but since i have enclosed it in updatePanel the change class code acts only for first time

Comment: were you also thinking that the "down" class should be removed when the "click" class is added? +1 on tandu's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you render your updatePanel, you need to execute those javascript once again, otherwise the former bound event will not be there, after updating.

Take a look at [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

If you have a jQuery Version before 1.7, you maybe need to use the `.delegate()` or `.live()` function.

So your code could be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnDiv .down").on("click",function () {
            $(this).addClass("click");
        });
    });
```

You don't need to render the above code every time you update your panel. Just execute once.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "UpdatePanel"  dynamically change its content. Then you need to use jquery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)) function to bind events for dynamically updated elements.